# How do I send authentication details in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ubuntu

I want to write a bash script which sends a password to authenticate with a remote server.

For example, I want to write a bash script which would pull the code from a github repository to a server, but I have to specify a password or passpharse to do it.

How am I supposed to code that? I tried couple of things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it was [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh) a lot but you could use [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). Here is an example of using it to connect to host using ssh:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set password "YOURPASSWORD"
set user "john"
set host "192.168.1.100"

spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "Password:"
send "$password\n";
interact
```

Replace "ssh user@host" with your command you want to execute, e. g. "git pull":

```
spawn git pull
```

The next line tells which prompt to expect ("Password:"). Make sure this string is set to exactly what appears after you manually do git pull. Case sensitivity and spaces are important.

**EDIT**: installing expect is easy, on Debian-based systems:

```
apt -y install expect
```

on RedHat-based:

```
yum -y install expect
```

Comment: Expect is a really nice tool to use, especially if you have commit / pull / etc hooks that prompt for additional input.

Comment: `autoexpect` is another good tool. I like to use that to create the original script, then go in and edit out the parts I think need fixing.