# How to write bash script that enters password after the first command?

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using expect to pass a password to ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh)

I want to have ssh connection to a remote machine and instead of using ssh command along with the machine address and password, I just want to write a little function that executes the ssh command to the machine and enters the pass after the server asks it. I can write the ssh part but how can I make the script that enters also the pass when the host ask for it?

Comment: Don't use passwords randomly stored in a text file! Use an ssh key instead.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That only works for the login password, not password prompts from the remote command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `expect` script. You can pass arguments from cmd line. Sample code I write:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 100
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set command [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh $username@$host $command
#puts $command
expect {
    "(yes/no)?"
        {
            send "yes\n"
            expect "*assword:" { send "$password\n"}
        }
    "*assword:"
        {
            send "$password\n"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Expect tool`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)
It's exactly what you need:

**EDIT**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 60
set user "yourName"
set machine "nameOfYourMachine"
set password "yourPassword"
set command "command that you want execute via ssh"
spawn ssh $user@$machine 
while {1} {
expect {
      eof                          {break}
      "The authenticity of host"   {send "yes\r"}
      "password:"                  {send "$password\r"}
      "*\]"                        {send "exit\r"}
      "bash"                        {send "$command"}
}
}
wait
close $spawn_id
```

Just workaround it as you need

Comment: @Erogol whrite #!/usr/bin/expect as first line

Comment: still dont work and getting spawn: command not found
while{1}{: command not found
couldn't read file "{": no such file or directory
No command 'eof' found, did you mean:
 Command 'eog' from package 'eog' (main)
 Command 'eox' from package 'keyboards-rg' (universe)
eof: command not found
*ssword:: command not found

Comment: @Erogol i edit my post check it now